# How can I do a 301 Redirect from HTTPS to HTTPS via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've done a bunch of research and have tried a lot of code to accomplish the following task and I am not having any luck. I am trying to forward the following:

from: https://www.oldwebsite.com
to: https://www.newwebsite.com

The reason behind the domain change was rebranding and SEO purposes. We do not have the old hosting available anymore, but I have added oldwebsite.com as an alias to the newwebsite.com. We are using GoDaddy's Wordpress hosting/installation.

Please note, the non-SSL (http://) forwards to the newsite.com with no issues; when someone clicks on an existing link with https://oldsite.com that is when the link breakage occurs. GoDaddy has recommended added the old domain as an alias (completed) and modifying the .htaccess file to perform the redirect, but it doesn't work.

Anyone have experience solving this issue?

Comment: What does "link breakage" mean?  Error message, 500 error, wrong redirect, blank page?  You'll need the SSL cert for the old domain installed if you want to redirect from https://old to https://new as well.  I suspect you're running into SSL errors, so see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32855990/892493) as it might help.

Comment: Thank you for your response here is the error I get:
This site can’t provide a secure connection
www.oldsite.com uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: Sometimes, not always, I then get the warning that "someone might be trying to steal your information". I am hoping to avoid purchasing a SSL cert. just to do a 301 redirect, but the cost and benefit outweighs the negative SEO effect of having broken links or unsecured warnings.

Comment: The first error might just be due to a semi-intentional SSL misconfiguration (being that SSL isn't configured for that host).  The second is the browser seeing something weird going on, but if you disable safe-browsing the error will be different.  Unfortunately, you'll have to get an SSL cert for the old domain if you want to avoid errors and warnings since prior to any htaccess rules being applied, the client and browser will have (attempted to) negotiate an SSL connection, and the client will need to have verified the domain matches the cert.

Comment: Otherwise I could just hijack someone's dns and silently redirect https://www.visa.com to http://vLsa.com/ and steal your info.  See the answer linked from my first comment for detail and where you can get inexpensive certs.