# How to redirect https to http in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I want to redirect my WordPress site from https to http, because the SSL certificate is expired. I've asked my host (strato) to extend the certificate, but they haven't fix it yet.

What I tried:

1. changed the site url
2. Installed plugin to force http
3. Deactivate all related SSl plugins

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: please share the code written in your `.htaccess` related this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress redirect all HTTPS to HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855861/wordpress-redirect-all-https-to-http)

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code,

Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP:

You want to redirect particular website to be opened through HTTP instead of HTTPS. To do so you can add the following directives in your website's .htaccess file:

```html
# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This worked great; I was working on a site migration that has been a pain in the neck and this disabled http requests assets when the site has an SSL certificate so that it loads with all styles and images.