# How to fix catch-22 with GCLB and Wordpress returning 301

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have setup a Kubernetes cluster on GKE. Installed the stable/wordpress Helm chart. Added an Ingress with a SSL certificate. But now the Google load balancer reports that my service is unhealthy. This is caused by the Wordpress pod that returns a 301 on the health check because it wants to enforce HTTPS, which is good. But the Google load balancer refuses to send a x-forwarded-proto: https header. So the pod thinks the health check was done over http. How can I work around this?

I have tried to add an .htaccess which always returns 200 for the GoogleHC User-agent but this is not possible with the helm chart which overrides the .htaccess after start-up.

Also see: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/937 and https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/18779

Answer (score 0):

**WAY : 1**

If you are using Kubernetes cluster on GKE then you can use ingress indirectly it will create the Loadbalancer indirectly.

You can add SSL certificate store it inside secret and apply to ingress. For SSL you can also choose another approach to install `cert-manager` on GKE.

If you want to setup nginx-ingress with cert-manager you can follow this guide also :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

**WAY : 2**

Edit the helm  chart locally add the `liveness` & `readinesss` probe to deployment and it will check wordpress health checkup over http only.

**Update** :

To add x-forwarded-proto in ingress you can use this annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /service {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      }
```

Comment: You didn't understand my problem. I have created an ingress which instantiates the load balancer indirectly. It has an SSL certificate which is obtained with cert-manager (no issues there). But because the SSL is terminated by the load balancer I want the LB to include the x-forwarded-proto header so the backend knows that the original request was through https and it won't redirect to https. But the LB doesn't do this for the health checks so it will get a 301 instead of a 200

Comment: in ingress you can use server-snippet annotation to add ` x-forwarded-proto`.updated answer update.

Comment: ok, I think it is more of a workaround then a solution. But it would probably work. Just a bit stupid that I can not fix this in a pro set-up with GKE.

Answer (score 0):

As the HTTPS load balancer terminates the client SSL/TLS session at the LB, you would need to [configure HTTPS between the load balancer and your application](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#https_tls_between_load_balancer_and_your_application) (wordpress). Health checks use HTTP by default, to use HTTPS health checks with your backend services, the backend services would also [require their own SSL/TLS certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#http_load_balancing)(See #4 of HTTP load balancing which HTTPS load balancing inherits). To make the backend certificates simpler to configure, you can use [self-signed certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#options_for_providing_ssl_certificates), which do not interfere with any client <-> load balancer encryption as the client session is terminated at the LB.

You can of course use HTTP health checks (less configuring!) for your backend(s), this will not cause any client traffic encryption issues, as it only affects the health check and not the data being sent to your application.

Comment: This isn't a solution either. I don't want to setup HTTPS in the backend, that defeats the purpose of terminating it at the LB.

Comment: The issue here is that Wordpress is forcing the HTTPS redirect (the 301), in which case, your options are either to configure GCP behind the LB to “play along” (enable HTTPS from LB -> Wordpress server with an internal self-signed certificate), or to configure Wordpress to respond to the HTTP requests without an HTTPS redirect. To get Wordpress to not perform the HTTPS redirect, this may be helpful (Kyle Vassella’s answer).

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855861/wordpress-redirect-all-https-to-http

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `https` between Load Balancer and Wordpress in the first place? Wouldn't it be enough to have `https` on Load Balancer frontend side(between LB and outside world)?
Do you have SSL termination done twice?

This is what I did when I was migrating my Wordpress site to GKE:

1. Removed all Wordpress plugins related to `https/ssl/tls`. Lukily for me it didn't even require any Db changes.
2. Added Google-managed certificate. With Google-managed certificates, it's very easy to add it. GKE even has a separate definition for a certificate. On top of that you just need to update your [DNS records](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#caa):

```
    apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta2
    kind: ManagedCertificate
    metadata:
      name: my-certificate
      namespace: prod
    spec:
      domains:
        #Wildcard domains are not supported(https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs).
        - example.com
    
    
    ---
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: prod-ingress
      namespace: prod
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
        kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: load-balancer-ip
        networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: my-certificate
```

I realize you have helm on top of it, but there's always a way to edit it/or configs/params.

Comment: Sorry but you didn't understand the question either. Wordpress enforces that the connection is over HTTPS. But if the load balancer doesn't tell the backend that the incoming connectionwas over https (by sending the x-forwarded-proto header as any other system would do) then there is absolutely no way for the backend to know that the connection was over https and it will redirect the user to the https url (which he used anyway). But I believe there currently is a way to do this with GKE LB.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't force HTTPS. It's plugins that you use inside it that do this. And if it's up to you - you can remove them.

Comment: No I can not because this is the default Helm chart that enforces this.

Comment: Got it then. Well, you always can create your own chart based on that one. People do it more often than you think. The more the charts encapsulate, the less flexible they become. In any case, it's not a good reason to have a redundant network element or additional TLS termination because of a chart that can't do without it.